# exclude hash sign with awk regexp

Tags: regex, awk

I have a file with the following:

```
#sometext=0 sometext=1 #sometext=5 sometext=34
```

and can't get

```
sometext=1
sometext=34
```

I have tried:

```
for (i=1; i<=4; i++){ 
   if ($i ~ /[^#]sometext=/){
   print $i
   }
}
```

but this is not working

Comment: Are you limited in using to `awk`?

Comment: yes, it should be only awk.

Comment: @Downvoters This is a valid question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
awk '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ( $i ~ /^sometext=/ ) print $i }'
```

**What it does?**

- `for (i=0;i<=NF;i++)` iterate through each column

  - `NF` , number of fields is the the total number of fields in each line
- `if ( $i ~ /^sometext=/ )` checks if the corresponding column starts with `sometext=`

**Test**

```
$ echo "#sometext=0 sometext=1 #sometext=5 sometext=34" | awk '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ( $i ~ /^sometext=/ ) print $i }'
sometext=1
sometext=34
```

Comment: I`ve edited my question to be clear. I need to extract from the string fields which are not starting with the hash sign.

Comment: @Ed Morton not strings but fields without hash sign and with `sometext` in it to be extracted.

Answer (score 1):

how about using simple? sed

```
$echo "#sometext=0 sometext=1 #sometext=5 sometext=34" | sed 's/#[^ ]*//g'
```

sometext=1 sometext=34

Comment: i have in mind reading Ed Morton advice book Effective gnu awk in near future

Comment: That would be Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins. It is applicable to all awks, not just GNU awk though that is covered too.

Comment: @bei You can actually combine that to single if  `if ( $i ~ /^sometext=/ )`

Comment: indeed, this one is simpler and clearer one! but why [^#] isnt working for awk?

Comment: here [^ ]* means any character which is not space, in Ed solution is pattern /^#/ which is starting with #. That is difference

Comment: ok, I thought that `[^#]` - is not # or empty, which seems to be wrong. but if i try ` /[^#]ometext/ ` it does not work too.

Comment: Ed, btw that upvote yourplace is from me. Someone's missing reward approach or lacking stack knowledge. When i post some question, every working solution is upvoted my side, best answer is accepted

Comment: @Ed&josifoski  indeed that is my firs question on this site, Im sorry if I was not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Or another awk version that is a bit leaner than @nu11p01n73R's answer:

```
echo "#sometext=0 sometext=1 #sometext=5 sometext=34" | awk '
    BEGIN{RS=" "}
    /^sometext/{print}
'
```

Which marks everything separated by a space as a new "record" and only *print*s the records that begin with *sometext*.